# An easy way to diff log files, ignoring the time stamps?

Tags: parsing, shell, diff, compare, logging

I need to diff two log files but ignore the time stamp part of each line (the first 12 characters to be exact).  Is there a good tool, or a clever awk command, that could help me out?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Depending on the shell you are using, you can turn the approach [@Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019/an-easy-way-to-diff-log-files-ignoring-the-time-stamps#44028) suggested into a 1-liner

```
diff <(cut -b13- file1) <(cut -b13- file2)
```

(+1 to [@Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019/an-easy-way-to-diff-log-files-ignoring-the-time-stamps#44028) for the original suggestion :-)

Comment: Any suggestions if one wants to keep the timestamps in the output but want to ignore differences in the timestamps themselves? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326476/how-to-diff-parts-of-lines#comment19909398_14326476

Comment: When I use this to diff the files in two directories, the names of the files are omitted in the output (if I just do `diff dir1 dir2` the names are included). Why? Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 26):

@EbGreen said

> I would just take the log files and strip the timestamps off the start of each line then save the file out to different files. Then diff those files.

That's probably the best bet, unless your diffing tool has special powers.
For example, you could

```
cut -b13- file1 > trimmed_file1
cut -b13- file2 > trimmed_file2
diff trimmed_file1 trimmed_file2
```

See @toolkit's response for an optimization that makes this a one-liner and obviates the need for extra files. If your shell supports it. Bash 3.2.39 at least seems to...

Comment: If someone's timestamps also have a date in ISO format, then use -b25-

Answer (score 20):

Answers using `cut` are fine but sometimes keeping timestamps within the `diff` output is appreciable. As the OP's question is about ***ignoring the time stamps*** (not removing them), I share here my tricky command line:

```
diff -I '^#' <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 1.log) <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 2.log)
```

- `sed` isolates the timestamps (`#` before and `\n` after) within a [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution)
- `diff -I '^#'` ignores lines having these timestamps (lines beginning by `#`)

---

### example

Two log files having same content but different timestamps:

```
$> for ((i=1;i<11;i++)) do echo "09:0${i::1}:00.000 data $i"; done > 1.log
$> for ((i=1;i<11;i++)) do echo "11:00:0${i::1}.000 data $i"; done > 2.log
```

Basic `diff` command line says all lines are different:

```
$> diff 1.log 2.log
1,10c1,10
< 09:01:00.000 data 1
< 09:02:00.000 data 2
< 09:03:00.000 data 3
< 09:04:00.000 data 4
< 09:05:00.000 data 5
< 09:06:00.000 data 6
< 09:07:00.000 data 7
< 09:08:00.000 data 8
< 09:09:00.000 data 9
< 09:01:00.000 data 10
---
> 11:00:01.000 data 1
> 11:00:02.000 data 2
> 11:00:03.000 data 3
> 11:00:04.000 data 4
> 11:00:05.000 data 5
> 11:00:06.000 data 6
> 11:00:07.000 data 7
> 11:00:08.000 data 8
> 11:00:09.000 data 9
> 11:00:01.000 data 10
```

Our tricky `diff -I '^#'` does not display any difference (timestamps ignored):

```
$> diff -I '^#' <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 1.log) <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 2.log)
$>
```

Change `2.log` (replace `data` by `foo` on the 6th line) and check again:

```
$> sed '6s/data/foo/' -i 2.log
$> diff -I '^#' <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 1.log) <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 2.log)
11,13c11,13
11,13c11,13
< #09:06:00.000
<  data 6
< #09:07:00.000
---
> #11:00:06.000
>  foo 6
> #11:00:07.000
```

**=> timestamps are kept in the `diff`output!**

You can also use the *side by side* feature using `-y` or `--side-by-side` option:

```
$> diff -y -I '^#' <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 1.log) <(sed -r 's/^((.){12})/#\1\n/' 2.log)
#09:01:00.000                   #11:00:01.000
 data 1                          data 1
#09:02:00.000                   #11:00:02.000
 data 2                          data 2
#09:03:00.000                   #11:00:03.000
 data 3                          data 3
#09:04:00.000                   #11:00:04.000
 data 4                          data 4
#09:05:00.000                   #11:00:05.000
 data 5                          data 5
#09:06:00.000                 | #11:00:06.000
 data 6                       |  foo 6
#09:07:00.000                 | #11:00:07.000
 data 7                          data 7
#09:08:00.000                   #11:00:08.000
 data 8                          data 8
#09:09:00.000                   #11:00:09.000
 data 9                          data 9
#09:01:00.000                   #11:00:01.000
 data 10                         data 10
```

---

### old `sed`

If your `sed` implementation does not support the `-r` option, you may have to count the twelve dots `<(sed 's/^\(............\)/#\1\n/' 1.log)` or use another pattern of your choice ;)

Comment: Thanks for your ingenious solution, this saved me hours of trying to do this in awk (and I would probably need to switch to perl to keep my sanity).

Comment: Yes! This is a great solution! This question comes up with some regularity, meld is one of the few tools that can do it, and it's *great* to have a command-line solution using only standard tools!

Answer (score 16):

For a graphical option, [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) can do this using its [text filters](http://meldmerge.org/help/text-filters.html) feature.

It allows for ignoring lines based on one or more python regex. The differences still appear, but lines that don't have any other differences won't be highlighted.

[image: Example configuration]

Answer (score 4):

Use **Kdiff3** and at **Configure>Diff** edit "**Line-Matching Preprocessor command**" to something like:

`sed "s/[ 012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]//"`

This will filter out time-stamps from comparison alignment algorithm.

Kdiff3 also lets you [manually align specific lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983314/manual-diff-alignment-in-kdiff3).

Comment: The files are still marked as different on every line but it allows me to search for real differences using the command **Go to Next / Previous Delta**.

Comment: And to do it straight from the command line:
`kdiff3 --cs LineMatchingPreProcessorCmd="sed \"s/[ 012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]//\"" "/path/to/file 1.txt" "/path/to/file 2.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

I want to propose a solution for Visual Studio Code:

1. Install this extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.partial-diff
2. Configure it like this - https://github.com/ryu1kn/vscode-partial-diff/issues/49#issuecomment-608299085
3. Run extension command "Toggle Pre-Comparison Text Normalization Rules" and enable rule added on step #2
4. Use the extension (here is an explanation of it's UI quirk - https://github.com/ryu1kn/vscode-partial-diff/issues/11)

Comment: Nice extension! Unfortunately, the displayed diff shows the normalized text (the result of the replacements performed by the normalization rules), rather than showing the original text (and merely ignoring parts of it for purposes of generating the difference highlighting). In contrast, Meld's text filters only apply for the sake of generating the diff.

Comment: The configuration is difficult if you're not familiar with it (the file to insert the fragment into is under File → Preferences → Profiles → Show Profile Contents, but do not edit it in VS code itself, your changes are silently discarded). The feature does not work if you select two files in the explorer sidebar and "Compare Selected". Instead you must "Select Text for Compare" in one tab and "Compare Text with Previous Selection" in the other. Toggling off the rule does not restore the original timestamp.