# Manual Diff Alignment in KDiff3

Tags: kdiff3

The "Add Manual Diff Alignment" in KDiff3 doesn't seem to do anything. The online documentation is rather sparse.

Does this function actually work?

Comment: Don't use Ctrl-Y to do manual alignment during a merge. You will lose all of your merges.

Comment: using Ctrl-Y during a merge seems to be fine as long as you do it before you start merging.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

To add manual diff alignment in KDiff3:

1. Put the cursor at the beginning of some text in one child window
2. Hit Ctrl+Y
3. Put the cursor at the beginning of some text in another child window
4. Hit Ctrl+Y

Comment: Can you add more details?  Which line should I select?  I tried selecting lines which were different, but should line up, and also tried selecting lines which were the same, but should line up.  Didn't notice any change to the diff.

Comment: It has been a while, but IIRC it works to click at the beginning of the text to compare and not have any text selected.

Comment: Is there a way to have more than one such alignment? I'm struggling and keep having to start from scratch.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've been using BeyondCompare for several years now, and it's quite rich in features. May be what you need, and it has a pretty generous trial period.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just faced this problem in kdiff3, and you can use this technique in multiple places in the same document.