# Compare particular column of two csv files using diff command

Tags: linux, csv, diff

I tried to compare two csv files using below command.

```
diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' test2.csv test.csv >> testfile3.csv
```

But I need to compare particular column of two csv files using diff command and get differed values.

For example:

```
file 1
1|9865|0|21
2|5698|0|22
3|2546|0|90

file2
1|9865|0|34
2|1452|9|33
3|2546|0|50

expected output:
2|5698|0|22
```

Give me your valuable suggestions/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` program cannot do this, since it compares only whole lines.  There are tools from which you can build a tool which does this.  Others have asked a similar question, e.g,.

- [compare two columns of different files and print if it matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches)
- [Using Diff on a specific column in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/using-diff-on-a-specific-column-in-a-file)
- [How to diff parts of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326476/how-to-diff-parts-of-lines)

The first two suggest using awk, while the third suggests a perl package.  The two suggestions for awk actually are for a *compare* rather than *diff*, are are correspondingly simplified.  If you do not need to worry about added/deleted lines, the approaches there would suffice.

The [perl package suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15811498/4518274) points out how to construct a *key*, which can be used to uniquely identify the value in (your case) a field from the csv file.  In your application, you would extract the column value, e.g., using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm).

Comment: There are different types of questions: how to approach a problem (asked and answered here), and how to repair a given program (there is none presented for discussion).